# how to use more than one sequence in forstep statement in PARI/GP?

Tags: loops, pari-gp

I am trying to write something in `PARI/GP`.
I want to create a vector with the values from 1000 to 41000 in steps of 3000.

Therefore, I wanted to use the forstep statement.
This works fine if you use 1 sequence.

Example:

```
forstep(x=1000,41000,3000,print(x))
```

However, I want to do something like:

```
forstep(x=1000,41000,3000,x[i]=x & i=i+1)
```

How to do this?

Comment: Why not to use just `start=1000; end=41000; step=3000; vector((end-start)/step, i, i)`?

Comment: @PiotrSemenov It will not work because of a couple of typos. This seems to be OK: `start=1000; end=41000; step=3000; vector((end-start)\step+1, i, start+(i-1)*step)`

Answer (score 0):

One way of making your approach work, is:

```
v=vector(14); i=1; forstep(x=1000,41000,3000,(v[i]=x) & (i=i+1)); v
```

I put a parenthesis around each assignment. Otherwise, PARI/GP sees it as `v[i]=(x & (i=i+1))`. So in some cases you *can* combine two expressions with `&`.

**However:** The operator `&` will short-circuit if its first operand is zero (seen as false). So the answer you are looking for, is the semicolon `;`. So:

```
v=vector(14); i=1; forstep(x=1000,41000,3000,v[i]=x; i=i+1); v
```

I believe a construct with semicolon like `v[i]=x; i=i+1` is called a *sequence* in the PARI/GP terminology.

Comment: And if you know the `++` syntax for incrementing, PARI/GP has that as well: `v=vector(14);i=0;forstep(x=1000,41000,3000,v[i++]=x);v`